# Ajax Big Post Data returns 500 error in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I written a plugin in WordPress that uses Ajax to save the plugin data. Problem is when the post size becomes big (see image):

[image]

The server throws error 500 . This does not happen with smaller post data size

Any idea ? I already tried post_max_size and seems to be not related with that.

The code is:

```
var mainarray = jQuery('.master-settings').serialize();
var data = {
        action: 'sliders_ajax',
    postdata: mainarray
};
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    if(window.console){
        console.log('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    }
    jQuery('#save-ajax-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    jQuery('.saveconfirmer').html('Options saved.');
    jQuery('.saveconfirmer').fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
});
return false;
```

Comment: Are you sending the request through `GET` or `POST`? Just making sure it's not because of the GET method's length limit. Show us some code also.

Comment: I suppose PHP don't have enough memory to process the uploaded file. What errors can you see in error.log?

Comment: @true it's not a uploaded file, it's a serialized array ( string )